# Zipcode , to_i and leading zero in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to save zip codes which are passed in the params as `"07306"`, and `"03452"`, but `to_i` seems to be converting these string values to `7306` and `3452` before validation, because of which the validation keeps failing.

How do I prevent Ruby from removing the leading zeros?

The zip code is an integer field in the database and the validation checks for the format of the zip using:

```
validates_format_of :zip, :with => /\A[+\-]?\d+\Z/, :message => "Please enter a valid US zipcode"
```

Comment: zipcode should not save as integer.

Answer (score 5):

It makes conceptually no sense to have a leading `0` when talking about an integer. Either format the zipcode when you use it (ie. make sure it has the right format, add a leading `0` when converting from int to str), or save it as a string

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I changed the field type to string to get the problem fixed

Comment: Save it as a string. There's no point saving strings of digits as a numeric if there is no math being performed against them.

Answer (score 5):

Saving it as a string instead will alleviate that issue, and also would help future-proof things if you decide to support foreign ZIP codes which may or may not have letters in them.

Comment: "may or may not have letters" or hyphens or spaces. Users can enter the darndest things.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I agree that it doesn't make sense to store zips as integers for just this reason. I also think you need to be very sure that you won't ever need non-US postal codes in your app. With those caveats out of the way, though...

If you are unable to modify the database for some reason, you can modify the get method for the zip code, like so:

```
def zip
  val = read_attribute(:zip).to_s
  val.length < 5 ? add_leading_zeros(val) : val
end

def add_leading_zeros(val)
  while val.length < 5 do
    val = "0" + val.to_s
  end
  val
end
```

It's kind of hacky, and I really don't recommend doing it this way if you can modify the DB field to be a string (varchar).

You might also want to modify the validation that you're using, as it will allow zip codes of less than 5 characters through.

Maybe use something like this:

```
validates_format_of :zip, :with => /^\d{5}$/
```

EDIT: I'll leave this answer here, but I just noticed that the OP already changed the field type in the DB... So, yeah, I feel a little silly for having typed all of this now.

Comment: This solution will break the validation in this scenario where in e  the user tries to input 4 digit zip which is not valid by rule and the add_leading_zeros will think that the user has sent a 5 digit zipcode with a leading zero and will append the zero and save it.

Comment: I have converted the field type to string to get the issue fixed